# List test names programatically in nose

Tags: nose

I want to do the equivalent of:

```
nosetests -v --collect-only <path_to_test_file>
```

inside a Python script, i.e. generate a list of test names, without generating any tests.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

One quick way to get it: run this exact command in python, but output test results into xml using `--with-xunit` and read xml file to get the list of tests. Alternatively make a quick plugin to sniff out tests.

Comment: That would work, I'll take a look at the plugin approach.  Thanks